# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform flutter error even though field exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my database and for one document, my retrieval code works but for all other document i get the error
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform.

Here is the code.
The widget being build is for now just showing the values in the 'temperature' field of the document for the chosen document(using docid).
I don't understand how it works for one document but not for the others.

widget.which is just the string 'temperature'. i used it because i was also doing this for pulse but for now, i just have temp sensor.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:sms_maintained/contact.dart';
import 'package:sms_maintained/generated/i18n.dart';
import 'package:sms_maintained/globals.dart';
import 'package:sms_maintained/sms.dart';

CollectionReference main = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('maindb');
SmsMessage message;

class biom extends StatefulWidget {
  biom({this.which, this.image, this.docid});
  final String which;
  final String docid;
  final String image;

  @override
  _biomState createState() => _biomState();
}

_callNumber(phoneno) async {
  print('in calling function');
  bool res = await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(phoneno.toString());
}

sendMessage(phoneno, curLat, curLong, flag) async {
  print('in sendmessage func');
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  curLat = position.latitude;
  curLong = position.longitude;
  //flag==0 is temp exceeds
  //flag==1 is distance outside
  SmsSender sender = SmsSender();
  String address = phoneno.toString();
  if (flag == 1) {
    print('in flag 1');
    message = SmsMessage(
        address, 'PATIENT HAS WANDERED: LOCATION IS $curLat ,$curLong ');
  } else {
    print('in flag 0');
    message = SmsMessage(address,
        'PATIENTS TEMPERATURE IS AT DANGEROUS LEVEL. PROVIDE AMBULANCE TO $curLat ,$curLong');
  }

  message.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
    if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
      print("SMS is sent!");
    } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
      print("SMS is delivered!");
    }
  });
  sender.sendSms(message);
}

distanceCalc(double lat, double long, int radius, phoneno) async {
  print('in function with $lat, $long');
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  double curLat = position.latitude;
  double curLong = position.longitude;
  print(
      'current lat is ${position.latitude},current long is ${position.longitude}');
  double distanceInMeters =
      await Geolocator.distanceBetween(lat, long, curLat, curLong);
  print('distance is $distanceInMeters meters');
  if (distanceInMeters > radius) {
    print('distance exceeds radius');
    sendMessage(phoneno, curLat, curLong, 1);
    _callNumber(phoneno);
  }
}

class _biomState extends State<biom> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('docid is ${widget.docid}');
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 80.0,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('images/${widget.image}.png',
                height: 100.0, width: 100.0),
            StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('maindb')
                    .doc(widget.docid)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text("Loading");
                  }
                  var userDocument = snapshot.data;
                  var phoneno = userDocument['phone'];
                  int radius = userDocument['radius'];
                  distanceCalc(userDocument['latitude'],
                      userDocument['longitude'], radius, phoneno);
                  if (userDocument['temperature'] > 29) {
                    print('temp is userDocument["${widget.which}"]');
                    sendMessage(phoneno, 0, 0, 0);
                    // _callNumber(phoneno);
                    print(
                        'calling because ${userDocument["${widget.which}"]} is greater than 31');
                  }
                  return CircleWidget(num: userDocument['temperature']);
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int num;
  CircleWidget({this.num});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150.0,
      width: 200.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black12,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0))),
      child: Center(
        child:
            Text(num.toString(), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the document and the screen for which the code works.
[image: works]
[image]

Here is one doc that doesn't work and the screen.
[image: no work]

[image: no]

ANSWER************
replaced snapshot.data with snapshot.data.data()

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshot.data` should be `snapshot.data.docs` and then iterate over them and get
something like `let Map<String, dynamic> doc = snapshot.data.docs[i].data().`

sidenote: change your naming convention. Class name with upper case, camel cases on variables etc

Edit: Try playing around with snapshot.data.data()

Comment: error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'. (undefined_getter at [vitality] lib\components\biom.dart:97)

Comment: also i don't need to iterate because i am only accessing 1 doc at a time. i was looking at multiple docs for testing purposes.

Comment: are you using the latest package for firebase? This is the old way to get the documents

Comment: yes i updated to latest package right now, same error

Comment: Try playing around with snapshot.data.data()